# How to export below Query Response in .rdf format from Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, rdf

I want to export the query response in .rdf format. I have created few nodes and relations. Now I need to export the Match Query result in .rdf format.
Now if I run the below statement, I gets the result, this result I want the export in .rdf format. How I can do that?

```
MATCH p=(n:Maths)-[r:HAS_TOPIC]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box there is no RDF serialization for a Neo4j graph. However, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/jbarrasa/neosemantics. That extension might have the capabilities you require.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7950075/tom-geudens) I had already the provided link. Didn't get any luck. would you please suggest some other link which can help me on this.

Comment: @amit325 I'm unaware of any other tool or extension that can do this for you, Neo4j is not a triple store after all ... you will need some form of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The extension in neosemantics that @TomGeudens shared with you should do the job. The problem is that the current release does not produce RDF output if your cypher query returns a path. To work around that limitation you can modify your query in two possible ways:

1. if the query is a simple pattern you can return the individual elements instead of the path
   `MATCH p=(n:Maths)-[r:HAS_TOPIC]->(x) RETURN n,r,x LIMIT 50`
2. If your query returns **necessarily a path**, you can add this unwind fragment at the end:
   `MATCH p=(n:Maths)-[r:HAS_TOPIC]->() WITH p LIMIT 25 UNWIND relationships(p) as rel RETURN rel, startNode(rel), endNode(rel)`

Either query should work on the rdf/cypher extension in neosemantics
You can test it in the browser typing `:POST /rdf/cypher " your query here "` and it should show on the screen the result as RDF (JSON-LD serialization).